# VS Code: Unable to attach to CoreCLR. Unknown Error: 0x80131c3c in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug c# dotnet 6 with visual studio code 1.68.1 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I'm getting this error:

**Unable to attach to CoreCLR. Unknown Error: 0x80131c3c**

I tryied to update visual studio code, enable and disable c# extension, uninstall and reinstall VS Code. Update and upgrade the OS and still not work.

The command in terminal `dotnet build` and `dotnet run` works.

Comment: Did you install the same runtime version of Core on deploy machine as the target in the build machine? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet

Comment: @jdweng yes I did.

Comment: The error seems to occur on Mac not Ubuntu.  Try doing a clean build.  I suspect you have obj files from another version of Net/Core that needs to be build with dot net 6.  Make sure the csproj file has target set to dot net 6.  Did you try updating the kernel?

Comment: This error is relevant in my case when trying to debug a linux-arm64 built executable from MacOS VS code. When publishing as self-contained executable - get the error. When publish as framework-dependant - debug works as expected.